# iTextSharp: Specify encoding when doing GetTextFromPage

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I'm using `iTextSharp` to extract some informations from a PDF file. Everything is almost perfect(quite impressed in fact), I just have some issue with some words.

By example, in the PDF, I've the following sentence:

> Dès la fin de soirée, [...]

When I look the PDF, I see exactly that, but when I receive the text from the following code:

```
ITextExtractionStrategy strategy = new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();
for (int page = 1; page <= pdfReader.NumberOfPages; page++)
{
    string currentPageText = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfReader, page, strategy);
    if (currentPageText.Contains(PAGE_MARKER))
    {
        return currentPageText;
    }
}
```

The text in question is the following:

> Dès la ﬁ n de soirée, [...]

It's strange, but the "fi" are in fact only one character, and there is a space.

When I open the same PDF in Foxit reader or Adobe acrobat, it's looking fine, but if I copy paste the text, I've the following text:

> Dès la fi n de soirée, [...]
>   (So the correct characters but with one space)

It's one example, but I've some another ones.

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

For this to make sense, you need some background in pdf syntax.

In the most rudimentary form, a pdf document contains only the instructions needed to render a document in a viewer. In other words, there is not concept of "text" being rendered. Just something like "draw character 'A' at location 150, 877" and so on.

In fact, this is a snippet from a .pdf document (opened with a simple text editor)

```
[a, -28.7356, p, 27.2652, p, 27.2652, e, -27.2652, a, -28.7356, r, 64.6889, a, -28.7356, n, 27.2652, c, -38.7594, e, 444] TJ
```

TJ is the "draw text" instruction. The array contains pairs for characters and their kerning info.

Now, for any kind of text extraction to work (both in iText and in the copy/paste functionality of Foxit, Adobe, etc) you need a bit of guesswork. (A heuristic as it commonly called).

You need to decide when some characters get stuck together and form a word, and when two characters are far enough apart that there should be a space between them.

In your usecase, it seems that the distance between "n" and  "i" is greater than the expected distance for that font.

Sadly, iText will not be able to (easily) help you there. Since the input document simply seems to be incorrect. Or rather most readers/viewers seem to be getting it wrong, so it is likely to simply be an issue in the pdf.

Of course, you can implement the TextExtractionStrategy. This class gives you access to the TextRenderInfo objects that contain the characters and graphic state in the pdf. Most TextExtractionStrategies will then check what the size of a space is in the font being used, and use that as a reference to decide when characters should be concatenated, and when they should be separated.

Lastly, if you want to delve deeper into this issue, you could always attach the input document.

Kind regards,
Joris

Comment: Thank you for the very interessting answser. This explains why I got some unexpected characters, but his doesn't explains the weird characters(like `ﬁ` instead of `fi`(first one is only one char in fact))

Comment: @J4N *"weird characters(like `ﬁ` instead of `fi`)"* - those are so called ligatures, i.e. glyphs showing two or three characters at once; these exist for some character combinations for which a custom combined glyph is considered to look clearly better than the individual glyphs set next to each other.

Comment: Well, in french they are some of them that are used(like "œ" instead of "oe", but except that, those are not even recognized in my charset. Is it possible to indicate to not convert them in the "ligature" version? To have the same version as the one in the PDF?

Comment: Yes. The pdf standard allows you to define something it calls "ActualText". ActualText is invisible, and only used for text-extracting. It helps in scenarios like yours, when the displayed text should be extracted as some other sequence of characters.

Comment: iText does allow you to take into account ActualText when doing text extraction. It also allows you to set ActualText when creating a document.

In the API for iText7 for instance, you'll find
http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/itext7/latest/com/itextpdf/kernel/pdf/canvas/parser/listener/LocationTextExtractionStrategy.html

Which allows you to set a flag useActualText. When this flag is set, the text extraction strategy will give precedence to the ActualText (if specified).